# A high road to the Kähler identities?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

Let $(X, \omega)$ be a compact Kähler manifold. The Kähler identities express the commutator relations between the operators $$\partial, \ \ \overline{\partial}, \ \ L,$$ and their adjoints. To be clear, $L : \Lambda^k \to \Lambda^{k+2}$ is the Lefschetz operator $\alpha \mapsto \alpha \wedge \omega$.

Although the identities are not hard to prove, remembering them is a challenge that I am yet to conquer. This leads me to ask whether there is a more enlightened perspective to be had when it comes to the Kähler identities.

**Edit:** This is also discussed in the following MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64520/global-algebraic-proof-of-the-kahler-identities

Comment: Do you want to try this in MO? It's already 2 weeks.. 7 upbotes 0 comments/answers is a good sign to move to MO :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I managed to find a similar post on MO, which I have linked in my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, let me post an answer. As alluded to [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64520/global-algebraic-proof-of-the-kahler-identities), the Kähler identities are local. Therefore, an algebraic proof largely misses the point. In more detail, the Kähler identities fundamentally use the fact that a Kähler metric affords coordinates in which it coincides with the Euclidean metric up to second-order. Hence, a coordinate-free, or algebraic proof would, at best, mask this property.